# Querystring in S3-Key

Tags: amazon-s3

It seems like you can upload files to s3 with a key including a questionmark, like:

test.html?p=1

But then i can not access it. If i try to access test.html?p=1 i will get the object stored with the key "test.html", is there some way to make this work? There is no problem if i end up on test.html if test.html?p=1 doesn't exist but if it exists i want to get that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try urlencoding your request?

Use %3F instead of the "?"